# Arithmetic progression question (given sum and 10th term)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

> The sum of the first $15$ terms of an arithmetic progression is $100$ and
>   its $10$th term is $5$. Find the $5$th term and then calculate the sum of the first $50$ terms.

It is my understanding that in-order to find the nth term of an arithmetic progression, the formula is:
$$T_n=a+(n-1)d$$
so
$$T_{10}=a+9d=5$$
However, I do not know the first number nor do I know the difference.

What is the correct formula to solve this question?

Comment: So what, in terms of $a$ and $d$, is the sum of the first fifteen terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

$$\frac{15}{2}\left(2a+(15-1)d\right)=100$$

$$a+(10-1)d=5$$

Solve for $a$ and $d$ first, then you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have the equations $$a_1+a_1+d+a_1+2d+...+a_1+14d=100$$
and $$a_1+9d=5$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the first $n$ terms of an arithmetic progression is

$$\frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}.$$ So we have

$$\frac{15(a_1+a_1+(14)d)}{2}=100,$$

and combining this with the fact that you have $$a_1+9d=5$$

gives you two equations with two unknowns...